# ¿Como crear un footer responsivo en bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Mi idea es crear un **footer responsivo** (que sirva para todas las pantallas) y que siempre quede debajo. Esto último no sucede, cuando reduzco el tamaño del navegador web, el footer tapa a los inputs del formulario y al desplazarte hacia abajo (con tab porque no funciona el scroll), el footer queda en la mitad de la pantalla..

**Mi code es el siguiente:**

```
<div class="company-info">
    <div class="w-100 primary" style="height: 50px; position:absolute; bottom:0">
        <div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-around pt-3">
            <div class="text-right">
                <p> <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> + {{ $company->phone }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right">
                <p> <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> {{ $company->email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cuando cambio el tamaño de la pantalla (navegador), parece detectarlo y adaptarse, el problema es cuando dejo de cambiar el tamaño y me desplazo hacia abajo mediante tabulaciones.

El code anteriormente mostrado esta dentro de:

```
<div class=“register-box”>
    <div class=“register-container”>
        <img> //img de fondo casi transparente
        <div class=“card”></div> //mi card con el formulario 
        <div class=“company-info”></div> //el code que he puesto anteriormente
    </div>
</div>
```

Donde:

```
.company-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

html, body, .register-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.register-box {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.register-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 2;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

He probado mover hacer esto:

```
<div class=“register-box”>
    <div class=“register-container”>
        <img> //img de fondo casi transparente
        <div class=“card”></div> //mi card con el formulario 
    </div>
</div>
<div class=“company-info”></div> //el code que he puesto anteriormente
```

Y siempre se encuentra debajo, o sea, en parte soluciona el problema, sin embargo, todo lo que no sea el footer parece tener un margen, mientras que el footer ocupa el 100% de la pantalla

Comment: Mete el row dentro de un container-fluid si quieres que tenga todo el ancho de pantalla. 1º tipo de container, 2º row y 3º tus col